# How to count frequency by range between two columns (string + float)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
FLIGHT HOUR UNSCHEDULED MAINTENANCE
18,73           NaN
44,36           NaN
69,99           AAAA
95,62           BBBB
121,25          NaN
146,88          NaN
172,51          CCCC
198,14          NaN
223,77          NaN
249,4           NaN
275,03          NaN
300,66          NaN
326,29          NaN
351,92          NaN
377,55          NaN
403,18          DDDD
428,81          NaN
454,44          NaN
481,56          NaN
508,81          NaN
536,06          NaN
563,31          NaN
590,98          NaN
```

And i want to count unscheduled maintenance, which is not a null value, within a frequency range of 100 FH. This should be the result:

```
BIN      FLIGHT HOUR    UNSCHEDULED MAINTENANCE
0-99        100                 2
100-199     200                 1
200-299     300                 0
300-399     400                 0
400-499     500                 1
```

I've tried to use pd.cut and value_counts without success.

Thanks in advance for any help you provide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `pd.cut` here:

```
# the max flight hour
max_hour=df['FLIGHT HOUR'].max()

# bins for cut
bins = np.arange(0,int(max_hour+100), 100)

(df['UNSCHEDULED MAINTENANCE'].notna()
   .groupby(pd.cut(df['FLIGHT HOUR'], bins=bins))
   .sum()
)
```

Output:

```
FLIGHT HOUR
(0, 100]      2
(100, 200]    1
(200, 300]    0
(300, 400]    0
(400, 500]    1
(500, 600]    0
Name: UNSCHEDULED MAINTENANCE, dtype: int64
```